You are not authorized to view this object, Django + Cloudflare R2
im trying to use CloudFlare R2 to server static files from my django project, but im having "This object could not be viewed".
I added custom domains, and allowed public view. I cant understand what is wrong.
Any help?
Thank you!


Your URL probably contains the bucket name. Remove the bucket name from the URL when using the custom domain and it'll work.
